# subprocessで外部プログラムから正しい値が返ってこない。

Tags: python, python3, line

Line messaging APIを使って気温を通知するのに挑戦しています。[こちら](https://github.com/line/line-bot-sdk-python/blob/master/examples/flask-kitchensink/app.py)のサンプルプログラムに下記コードを追加しLINEから"気温"と実行したらエラーが吐き出されました。どうすれば気温が通知されるでしょうか？

#### app.py

```
elif text == '気温':
        cmd = ["python3", "dth11.py"]
        proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
               stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
        temp = proc.stdout.read().decode("utf-8")
        line_bot_api.reply_message(event.reply_token, TextSendMessage(text=temp))
```

#### dth11.py

```
import Adafruit_DHT as DHT

SENSOR_TYPE = DHT.DHT11
DHT_GPIO = 22
h,t = DHT.read_retry(SENSOR_TYPE, DHT_GPIO)
print("現在の部屋の気温は{0:0.1f}度、湿度{1:0.1f}%です。".format(t,h))
```

#### エラー内容

```
python3: can't open file 'dth11.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

app.pyとdth11.pyは同じディレクトリに置いてあります。よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

単純にファイル名が間違っていました。dth11.pyをdht11.pyにしたら直りました。

Comment: `dth22.py` が存在しないというエラーが出ているようですが、それも解決しましたか？

Comment: dth11.pyの間違いでした。